# Is there an R function that captures the email of a user that logs in to Power BI?

Tags: r, powerbi

I'm planning to create a predictive model for retail at the store-level. I'll be dealing with thousands of stores, so this will entail a very huge data. Since my computer's capability is very limited, I was thinking of filtering the dataset based on who is logged in to Power BI to reduce the size before proceeding with the modelling part in my code. I use Power BI as my visualization tool and later on, the R code that I will create will be imported to Power BI Desktop.

Comment: surely you'll need credentials to some kind of powerbi system database, and/or your company's machine which runs the service. in R you could then connect using the `DBI ` package to that database and retrieve the connected users.

Comment: Can you use row level security in Power BI (filtering on username), it will filter using direct query mode no problem. But if you import the data, it will not (r or M) pass down a parameter to filter the data then import it. Also if you are doing R in the Power Query part, you'll not be able to use it in the PBI service, unless you are consuming data from an on premise system, and will be limited to a 'Personal Data Gateway'

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I'm guessing that you are using the R-visualisation in Power BI desktop.
if that is the case you could pass a measure to the R-visualisation with the username:

```
logged in user = Username()
```